# Event not firing/being caught

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have a class DiscordClient that I would like to emit events because I want other classes to be able to respond to them. But, either the event is not firing or it is not being caught.

The results that I am getting are that console.log calls within the instantiated class in the `on_connect()` and `on_message()` methods are going to the console, however, the callback functions in `index.js` are not being called (I think?). Anyway, nothing's happening there. And I've tried re-ordering things, but nothing I've tried is helping.

**discordclient.js**

```
require("dotenv/config")
const { EventEmitter } = require("events")
const Discord = require("discord.js")

class DiscordClient extends EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.client = new Discord.Client()
        this.client.on( "ready", this.on_connect )
        this.client.on( "message", this.on_message )
    }

    connect() {
        this.client.login(process.env.DISCORD_TOKEN)
    }

    on_connect() {
        this.emit("discord_connected")
        console.log("Connected to Discord server.")
    }

    on_message( message ) {
        const payload = {
            name   : `${message.member.displayName}`,
            channel: `${message.channel.name}`,
            message: `${message.content}`
        }
        
        this.emit( "discord_message", payload ) 
        console.log( payload )
    }
}

module.exports = DiscordClient
```

**index.js**

```
"use strict"

const DiscordClient = require("./discordclient")

const discord = new DiscordClient()
const discordConnected = () => console.log( "Connected to Discord server.") 
const discordMessage = data => console.log( data )
discord.on( "discord_connected", discordConnected )
discord.on( "discord_message", discordMessage )
discord.connect()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to make sure you bind your callbacks to the current object.

```
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.client = new Discord.Client()
        this.client.on( "ready", this.on_connect )
        this.client.on( "message", this.on_message )
    }
```

Needs to be:

```
    constructor() {
        super()
        this.client = new Discord.Client()
        this.client.on( "ready", this.on_connect.bind( this ) )
        this.client.on( "message", this.on_message.bind( this ) )
    }
```

Ie. I added `bind( this )` to each assigned callback.